# grep not working with filename from for loop

Tags: linux, bash, grep

learning bash scripting and i'm trying to filter results with a nested grep in a for loop:

```
sample filenames:
  this-file_AAC.txt
  this-other_file_AAAC.txt
  yep-a-file_AAC.nfo
  oops_another_one.reamde
```

and this is the script:

```
shopt -s globstar nullglob dotglob
for file in ./**/*.{txt,reamde,nfo}; do
  printf "input: ${file}\n"
  if grep -qF _AAC $file; then
    printf "output: ${file}\n"
    # do stuff with $file
  fi
done
```

the idea being any file that contains `_AAC` will have operations applied to it; in this specific case, just print to stdout to confirm the results are correct.

problem is:  nothing makes it past the `if` statement.  so i'm missing i-don't-know-what.  all that works is the `printf "input...` line.

what am i missing?

Comment: `grep` is looking inside the *content* of the file... are you trying to apply a command if the *name* of the file contains _AAC?

Comment: yes.  i thought `grep` worked on a filename as well... sounds like it doesn't?

Comment: `for file in ./**/*_AAC*.{txt,reamde,nfo}; do ...`

Comment: @roaima  can this be *negated* like so `for file ! in ./**/*_AAC*....`?

Comment: No, but your question wanted matches, not anti-matches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where your script says:

```
  if grep -qF _AAC $file; then
```

it is saying, "if the contents of the file named `$file` contain the literal string `_AAC` then ...." execute the contents of the `then` block.

If what you mean is to instead search for `_AAC` in the string resulting from the expansion of the variable `$file` (i.e. to check whether _AAC appears in the filename itself), then in `bash`, you need to write:

```
  if grep -qF _AAC <<< "$file"; then
```

Or, as @roaima points out, the literal string you're searching for can be included in the wildcard file specification.

Comment: Just use a glob. There's no need for `grep` here at all

Comment: And it's worth noting the variable surrounded by doueble quotes, which OP doesn't have.

Comment: and even if you have the filename in a variable, use `case $file in *_AAC*) ... ;; esac` or `[[ $file == *_AAC* ]]` in shells that have it

Comment: boop.  that's the bunny right there.  thank you!  very useful knowledge.  much appreciated.  :)

Comment: @roaima  don't know how to use a `glob` in bash.  PHP, yes.  Python, yes.  Bash, no.  :P

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity just to complete the loop (haha), i presume i can *negate* this like so: `if ! grep -qF _AAC <<< "$file"; then`?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to match all files that are named like `.../something_AACxyz`, with `_AAC` in the last filename part, just add the `_AAC` part directly to the glob pattern/wildcard:

```
for file in ./**/*_AAC*.{txt,reamde,nfo}; do
```

---

If you want filenames where `_AAC` can appear in any part, you could do (in Bash):

```
for file in ./**/*.{txt,reamde,nfo}; do
    if [[ $file == *_AAC* ]]; then
         echo "'$file' contains _AAC"
    else
         echo "'$file' has NO _AAC"
    fi
done
```

Here, you also get the files that match the globs, but don't have `_AAC`.

---

In any case, on Bash, you could also enable `extglob` and rewrite the pattern with `@(...|...)` instead of the brace expansion:

```
for file in ./**/*_AAC*.@(txt|reamde|nfo); do
```

The brace expansion produces multiple distinct globs, while with `@(..)` it's just a single glob. (i.e. `*.{foo,bar}` is the same as `*.foo *.bar`) With `nullglob` set the non-matching ones don't matter, but if you had `failglob` set, just one non-matching one would be enough to fail the whole command.

Comment: this is fantastic!  thank you!  wow.  this has been a very productive and useful post!  thanks again @ikkachu.